# I cannot see all versions of a NuGet Pacakge

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget

I am doing some investigation of NuGet to determine if I can use it to distribute various software components. All of these components are C++ based so I'm using CoApp PowerShell Tools to create the NuGet package files. I have placed these .nupkg files on a network folder for distribution. However, when accessing the packages via Visual Studio 2012, I can only see the latest version. Is there a way to view all of the versions of a particular package?

Here is the network folder:
[image: Network folder]

Here is what I see in Visual Studio 2012:
[image: Visual Studio Packages]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're supposed to only see the latest version.  If you want to install a specific version, you'll have to use the Package Manager Console.

```
Install-Package SYS_STANDARDS -Version 1.3.1.0
```

If that isn't acceptable for your requirements, then Nuget isn't the best way to distribute your code.

Comment: Great! Thanks. I don't know that it's not acceptable, I was just confused as to why it doesn't show up. My guess is that most of this will be done via scripts not manually. Thanks for the quick reply.

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of Visual Studio have a drop down menu that can be opened to view and select different versions of a package

[image]

Comment: I see it now. I wonder why I wasn't seeing it a few days ago. (no changes to VS)